# Tableau: How to get an overview of who have accessed a Dashboard?

Tags: database, tableau-api

I am trying to create an overview of the users who have accessed a particular Tableau Dashboard. Preferably, the overview should display statistics of the users' activity on a country level, departmental registration number, region, and the individual user-id of those who have accessed it. I have the data on a local database. However, I cannot find any neat solutions to this online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use Tableau Server.

I'm sending you the link `http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/adminview_bucket.htm`.

You have the option to use Administrative views pre-built or get it customised. All the information should be in the right-hand side.

Hope you find this useful.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Juanma! That is helpful.